# Sound too low when making calls on Moto G smartphone

Tags: audio, calls, motorola-moto-g

Everything is perfect, except that the call volume is way too low. I can barely hear it when it is completely silent, and if I'm at a coffee shop or something, no chance.

Now, this would seem to be a hardware issue except that plenty of people seem to have the problem and it has only occurred since the latest Kit-Kat update.  Solutions seem to vary, from hitting both volume buttons at once, to resetting the device to factory settings.

Suffice to say, none of these have worked for me and has really put a damper on my otherwise awesome Android.

So my question is, does anyone have a solid solution to the problem, or should I just wait around to see if Google deigns to fix it at some point.

Comment: To clarify, the voice that comes out of the earpiece when talking is too low

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your call quality volume is too low and the device is at its maximum volume, you may want to try a Volume Booster. [Speaker Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.SpeakerBoost) by Omega Centauri Software does the trick for me, even with phone calls.

There are better "Volume Boosters", though, but the one by the developer I mentioned works best for my device. There are deducted volume boosters for phone calls on the Play Store, though I haven't tested the one other than the one I linked, so I won't link those.

Answer (score 1):

If the volume while a call is full and you still think it's low then, try use any voice boaster app from playstore  it will help you to hear voice more louder but distorted

Answer (score 0):

While you are calling you should press the " + " button. If you are at the home screen and then press the " + " button, the ringtone volume will be louder.

Comment: I think the question is revering to ringer volume when in a call not ringtone volume

Comment: @Sjharrison That's what the first sentence is for. The second sentence just explains why it doesn't work on the home screen.

Comment: Sorry my misunderstanding, however in the question the user stated that the problem has arose since the KitKat update, the feature that @tom mentioned is available in JB therefore it seems unlikely that this is the solution

Answer (score -1):

Anti noise feature can cause that . you try can deactivat it .
Make a call then click menu button it should be deactivated frol there .